# Rolling correlations across multiple columns, some with NAs?

Tags: r

I have the below dataset, where I am trying to do a rolling 3 days correlation across x,y,z,a. So the code should do rolling correlations of xy,xz,xa, yx, yz,ya and so on. Also, as you can see below, the data for y and a is incomplete, but I would wish to do rolling correlations of them starting from the date where they first had values (i.e. id 3 and id 4).

How should I accomplish this? Don't know where to start...

```
set.seed(42) 
n <- 10
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
                  date=seq.Date(as.Date("2020-12-22"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "day"),
                  x=rnorm(n),
                  y=rnorm(n),
                  z=rnorm(n),
                  a=rnorm(n))
dat$y[1:2] <- NA
dat$a[1:3] <- NA
```

I am able to find this set of code from stack, but it only helps in finding the answer for 1st column and not all the columns

```
rollapplyr(x, 5, function(x) cor(x[, 1], x[, -1]), by.column = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data frame with only the columns wanted and then use `rollapplyr` with `cor`.  `cor` takes a `use=` argument that specifies how missing values are to be handled.  See `?cor` for the values it can take since you may or may not wish to use the value we used below.

The result `r` is a matrix whose i-th row describes the correlation matrix of the 5 `dat2` rows ending in and including row `i`.  That is, matrix(r[i, ], 4, 4) is the correlation matrix of `dat2[i-(4:0), ]`.

We can also create `ar` which is a 3d array which is such that `ar[i,,]` is the correlation matrix of the 5 rows of dat2 ending in and including row `i`.

That is these are equal for each i in 5, ..., nrow(dat2).  (The first 4 rows of r are all NA since there do not exist 5 rows leading to those rows.)

```
1. cor(dat2[i-(4:0), ], use = "pairwise")
2. matrix(r[i, ], 4, 4)
3. ar[i,,]
```

We run checks for these equivalences for i=5 below.

```
library(zoo)
w <- 5
dat2 <- dat[c("x", "y", "z", "a")]
nr <- nrow(dat2)
nc <- ncol(dat2)


r <- rollapplyr(dat2, w, cor, use = "pairwise", by.column = FALSE, fill = NA)
colnames(r) <- paste(names(dat2)[c(row(diag(nc)))], 
                     names(dat2)[c(col(diag(nc)))], sep = ".")

ar <- array(r, c(nr, nc, nc), 
  dimnames = list(NULL, names(dat2), names(dat2)))

# run some checks

cor5 <- cor(dat2[1:w, ], use = "pairwise") # cor of 1st w rows

# same except for names
all.equal(unname(cor5), matrix(r[w, ], nc))
## [1] TRUE

all.equal(cor5, ar[w,,])
## [1] TRUE
```

The above shows a matrix whose rows are strung out correlation matrices and a 3d array whose slices are correlation matrices.  Another possibility for output is to create a list of correlation matrices.

```
lapply(1:nr, function(i) {
  if (i >= w) cor(dat2[i-((w-1):0), ], use = "pairwise")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`combn` produces all the combinations.

```
cols <- c("x", "y", "z", "a")

combn(cols, 2)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,] "x"  "x"  "x"  "y"  "y"  "z" 
# [2,] "y"  "z"  "a"  "z"  "a"  "a"
```

`combn` has a function argument where you first `na.omit` all rows with `NA's`. Then subset with `mapply` over incrementing sequences `1:3` and calculate correlations, until `nrow` is reached.

```
w <- 3  ## size of the rolling window
combn(dat[cols], 2, function(x) {
  X <- na.omit(x)
  n <- nrow(X)
  mapply(function(y, z) cor(X[y + z, 1], X[y + z, 2]), list(1:w), 0:(n - w))
}, simplify=FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1]  0.5307784 -0.9874843 -0.8364802  0.2407730  0.3655328 -0.4458231
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  0.8121466  0.9652715  0.3304100  0.8278965 -0.1425097  0.5832558  0.9959705
# [8]  0.8696023
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  0.6733985  0.2194488  0.5593983 -0.6589249 -0.9291184
# 
# [[4]]
# [1]  0.97528684 -0.90599558 -0.42319742  0.92882443  0.28058418  0.05427966
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] -0.7815678 -0.7182037 -0.6698260  0.4592962  0.7452225
# 
# [[6]]
# [1]  0.9721521  0.9343926 -0.3470329 -0.7237291 -0.6253825
```